# Which among the following is true for a Wronskian Of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions of the differential Equation

$y^{"} + P(x)y^{'} + Q(x)y = 0$ on $[a,b]$, Let $W(u,v)$ denote the Wronskian Of $u$ and $v$ Then

(a) $W(u,v)$  vanishes at point $x_{0} \in [a,b]$ $\implies$ $u,v$ are Linearly Dependent.

(b) $W(u,v)$ is identically zero  on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $u,v$ are Linearly Dependent

Now ,I  Know from this question [Proof that ODE solutions with Wronskian identically zero are linearly dependent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143686/proof-that-ode-solutions-with-wronskian-identically-zero-are-linearly-dependent?rq=1) That option (b) must be correct.

For option (a) We know that Wronskian for Differential Equation is either identically Zero or Never Zero, so if Wronskian vanishes at one point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ it must vanish identically in $[a,b]$ so option (a) is also correct.

So both options (a) and (b) must be true for this question.

Is My answer correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition

$W(u, v) = \det \begin{bmatrix} u & v \\ u' & v' \end{bmatrix} = uv' - vu' \tag 1$

we find

$W'(u, v) = u'v' + uv'' - v'u' - vu'' = uv'' - vu''; \tag 2$

using the fact that $u$ and $v$ are both solutions of

$y'' + P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0, \tag 3$

we may transform (2) to

$W'(u, v) = u(-P(x)v' - Q(x)v) - v(-P(x)u' - Q(x)u) = -P(x)uv' - Q(x)uv + P(x)vu' + Q(x)uv = -P(x)(uv' - vu') = -P(x)W(u, v); \tag 4$

the solution to this ordinary linear equation for $W(u, v)$ is readily seen to be

$W(u, v)(x) = \exp \left (-\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s) \; ds \right )W(u, v)(x_0); \tag 5$

under fairly mild conditions on $P(x)$ we may affirm that

$\forall x, \; \exp \left (-\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s) \; ds \right ) \ne 0, \tag 6$

and thus

$W(u, v)(x_0) \ne 0 \Longrightarrow \forall x, W(u, v)(x) \ne 0,  \tag 7$

and likewise,

$W(u, v)(x_0) = 0 \Longrightarrow \forall x, W(u, v)(x) = 0;  \tag 8$

these well-known results (6)-(8) establish a bidirectional linkage 'twixt our OP sat091's hypotheses (a) and (b); certainly (b) implies (a), and from what we have done here we have been able to conclude that the weaker (a) yields (b); thus our OP sat091 is correct on both counts.