# Why is it that solutions $x_1 \text{ and } x_2 \text{ to a differential equation are linearly dependent } \iff W(x_1,x_2)(t_0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Can someone explain  from where the aforementioned fact is derived? By the way $W = \text { Wronskian determinant}.$

Comment: [Thiis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143686/proof-that-ode-solutions-with-wronskian-identically-zero-are-linearly-dependent?rq=1) might help!, also observe that linear dependence implies zero Wronskian but not the converse, so the two sided implication is not correct, it should be a one sided $\implies$ implication.

Comment: @BAYMAX OP has stated in the title "solutions to the differential equation...". The backwards direction becomes correct if you assume this additionally, more exactly, they have to solve a linear ODE, as written in the answer you have linked.

Comment: The notation $W(x_1(t_0),x_2(t_0))$ doesn't make much sense  - probably you meant $W(x_1,x_2)(t_0)$.

Answer (score -1):

For the non-trivial direction, suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to $$x''+bx'+cx=0,$$define $$W=x_1x_2'-x_1'x_2,$$and assume $$W(t_0)=0.$$Define $$y(t)=x_2'(t_0)x_1(t)-x_1'(t_0)x_2(t).$$Of course $y$ is a solution to the original DE, being a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$. It's clear that $y'(t_0)=0$, and $W(t_0)=0$ shows that $y(t_0)=0$. So uniqueness shows that $$y(t)=0,$$which says that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are dependent.