# Find general solution of Differential equation if you know three solutions. Is there exist general solution if Wronskian is zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Find general solution of Differential equation if you know three solutions. I tried to solve this problem, however I have a question about the Wronskian. Three particular solutions are 1, $x$, ${x^2}$. I know, that general solution can be written as $C_1{(x^2-1)} +C_2{(x-1) + 1}$, because difference of two particular is general. However, there is a theorem that says if Wronskian equals zero in one point, then the functions are linearly dependent. [Proof that ODE solutions with Wronskian identically zero are linearly dependent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143686/proof-that-ode-solutions-with-wronskian-identically-zero-are-linearly-dependent). And I'm stuck here, ${W[x^2-1,x-1]}$ is zero when ${x=1}$, so this functions can't form a general solution, as they linearly dependent. But in the textbook $C_1{(x^2-1)} +C_2{(x-1) + 1}$ is a solution, where is a mistake in my reasoning? I totally understand that ${1,x,x^2}$ are linearly independent, I just want to understand, why this theorem doesn't work and where is my mistake. I can also give a proof  of the theorem, as short, as I can: let's consider ${y(x)}$ is a solution to a differential equation with general solution $C_1{(x^2-1)} +C_2{(x-1)}$, then ${y(x) = C_1{(x^2-1)} +C_2{(x-1)}.}$ Let ${C_1 = 1, C_2=-2}$. ${y(1) =0}$ and ${y'(1)=0}$ and there exists only one solution by existence and uniqueness theorem. Therefore ${y(x)=0}$ and $C_1{(x^2-1)} +C_2{(x-1)}$ linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify that $y(x)=C_1(x^2-1)+C_2(x-1)$ is the general solution to the second order linear ODE
$$
y''-\frac{2}{x-1}y'+\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}y=0. \tag{1}
$$
The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680662) of the theorem you mention assumes that the coefficients $p_0(x), p_1(x),\ldots,p_{n-1}(x)$ of the linear differential equation
$$
y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+p_1(x)y'+p_0(x)y=0 \tag{2}
$$
*are continuous*. In Eq. $(1)$, however, $p_0(x)=\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}$ and $p_1(x)=-\frac{2}{x-1}$ are not continuous at $x=1$, so the vanishing of the Wronskian $W[x^2-1,x-1]$ at $x=1$ does not imply that $x^2-1$ and $x-1$ are linear dependent functions.